# How do I leave only last commit on my master branch?

Tags: git

I want to delete all previous commits from my master branch and leave only latest commit. What series of commands shall I execute locally and then push into origin to make this happen?

Comment: Do you want to keep other branches?

Comment: No. All I want master branch with current commit